# ___ is the best ___ I like

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, superlatives

Does this sentence make sense?

**Beer is the best drink I like.**

Is that very different from *"Beer is my favorite drink."*?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily we say *Beer is the drink I like best*, with *best* an adverb modifying *like*.

*Beer is the best drink I like*, with *best* as an adjective modifying *drink* would mean something different. This statement distinguishes beer from other drinks you like not by the intensity of your liking for it but by its superiority on some scale of goodness which is a quality of the beer itself.

> I like beer, tea and coffee, and in fact I like coffee best; but beer is the best drink I like because it is nutritious and has no caffeine.

Comment: What if I say "Beer is the drink I like the most."?

Comment: @Bora That's fine, too.

Comment: But an online test didn't accept my answer (The cake with hazelnuts is the cake I like best). It says answer should have been "The cake with hazelnuts is the cake I like the most."

Comment: @Bora I am shocked, *shocked* I tell you, to hear that an [online](https://xkcd.com/386/) test of English idiom should make a mistake.

Comment: @Bora - Why do you add this bit about the cake with the hazelnuts **after** someone has answered your question? Your question would have been much better had all that been included from the beginning.